# Error message in INSERT Statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I believe there is something wrong with my INSERT statement here. When I run my code, the error message shows:

> Line: 5
>   Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Incorrect syntax near ','.

Is is something wrong in my where clause?

Here is my `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT into AppointmentDetails (SelectedApptDate, SelectedApptStartTime, 
                                SelectedApptEndTime, SelectedWeddingPlanner) 
   SELECT 
       ApptID 
   from 
       Appointment 
   INNER JOIN 
       Appointment ON Appointment.ApptID = AppointmentDetails.ApptID 
   WHERE 
       SelectedApptDate = @SelectedApptDate, 
       SelectedApptStartTime = @SelectedApptStartTime, 
       SelectedApptEndTime = @SelectedApptEndTime, 
       SelectedWeddingPlanner = @SelectedWeddingPlanner
```

This is how I call it from C#:

```
    command.CommandText = "INSERT into AppointmentDetails (SelectedApptDate, SelectedApptStartTime, SelectedApptEndTime, SelectedWeddingPlanner) SELECT ApptID from Appointment INNER JOIN Appointment ON Appointment.ApptID = AppointmentDetails.ApptID WHERE SelectedApptDate = @SelectedApptDate, SelectedApptStartTime = @SelectedApptStartTime, SelectedApptEndTime = @SelectedApptEndTime, SelectedWeddingPlanner = @SelectedWeddingPlanner";

    command.Connection = connection;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedApptDate", dateSelected);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedApptStartTime", timeStart);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedApptEndTime", timeEnd);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedWeddingPlanner", weddingplanner);
```

Comment: Your INSERT statement has four columns and your SELECT statement is only returning one column.  That is the main problem with your statement.  Also, your WHERE clause is formatted incorrectly.  You should be using AND or OR instead of commas between conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `AND` instead of `,` to separate between the conditions in the `WHERE` clause. You have to write it this way:

```
INSERT into AppointmentDetails (SelectedApptDate, SelectedApptStartTime,
           SelectedApptEndTime, SelectedWeddingPlanner) 
SELECT ApptID 
from Appointment 
INNER JOIN Appointment ON Appointment.ApptID = AppointmentDetails.ApptID 
WHERE SelectedApptDate = @SelectedApptDate
   AND  SelectedApptStartTime = @SelectedApptStartTime
AND SelectedApptEndTime = @SelectedApptEndTime 
AND  SelectedWeddingPlanner = @SelectedWeddingPlanner";
```

However you will got a new exception after that, since you only select one column to insert into these four columns: `SelectedApptDate, SelectedApptStartTime, SelectedApptEndTime, SelectedWeddingPlanner`. You have to specify the other three columns as well in the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: What do all of you mean by defining 3 more SELECT columns? I had changed my comma to AND and it gives another error which many of you have stated. What I am actually thinking is that I have 2 tables in my database which consists of Appointment and AppointmentDetails. My ApptID is a foreign key in my AppointmentDetails table and if i were to insert values into my AppointmentDetails table, I would need to also map my ApptID in my AppointmentDetails table to my ApptID in my Appointment table. Is that right?

Comment: @kelly, Instead of `... SELECT ApptID ...` it should be `... SELECT apptID, anotherColumn, SecondColumn, ThirdColumn ...`

Comment: ThankYou so much for your help! I do not have any errors now but I am unable to insert successfully into the database.

Answer (score 2):

You don't separate `WHERE` clauses with `,`; did you mean `AND`?

```sql
INSERT INTO
    AppointmentDetails (SelectedApptDate, SelectedApptStartTime, SelectedApptEndTime, SelectedWeddingPlanner)
    SELECT ApptID FROM Appointment INNER JOIN Appointment ON Appointment.ApptID = AppointmentDetails.ApptID
    WHERE SelectedApptDate = @SelectedApptDate
      AND SelectedApptStartTime = @SelectedApptStartTime
      AND SelectedApptEndTime = @SelectedApptEndTime
      AND SelectedWeddingPlanner = @SelectedWeddingPlanner
```

You'll also need to `SELECT` four columns, not just one.

Answer (score 1):

You only have one column in your SELECT statement, yet the INSERT expects four columns.  What does the schema look like?

What fields are you trying to pass into your INSERT from the table Appointment, and which are supposed to be coming from variables?

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause should contain `AND` or `OR`.

For example:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT into AppointmentDetails (SelectedApptDate,   
                                                       SelectedApptStartTime,  
                                                       SelectedApptEndTime,  
                                                       SelectedWeddingPlanner)

SELECT ApptID from Appointment 
INNER JOIN Appointment ON Appointment.ApptID = AppointmentDetails.ApptID
WHERE  SelectedApptDate = @SelectedApptDate 
AND SelectedApptStartTime = @SelectedApptStartTime
AND SelectedApptEndTime = @SelectedApptEndTime
AND SelectedWeddingPlanner = @SelectedWeddingPlanner";
```

Also, your `INSERT` statement contains 4 columns, but you are only returning 1 column in your `SELECT` statement.